# What's the best way to design app widget for Honeycomb tablets?

Tags: android, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-appwidget

I've been studying a few pages on the Android developer site, including this one:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#sizes

However, they all use the (cell x 74dp) - 2dp measure, and that doesn't seem to be working properly for Honeycomb tablets, as they have a higher screen resolution and size. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not even sure if these are dp, as I guessed [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395349/should-android-widget-backgrounds-be-nine-patch-should-there-be-different-dpi-ve/7395420#7395420), the doc may as well be written for 1.5. and never be touched again. 1.5. supported basically only one resolution: HVGA (320x480). I write my widgets with dynamic layouts like every other, normal layout. I keep in mind the size might change and don't use fixed dimensions consequently, which worked great so far. *(But I only own phones, no tablet yet - so take this with a grain of salt)*

Comment: The only problem is that I would like to get a fixed start resolution. Android 3.1 can resize widgets, and I will support that, but I'd like a minimum starting resolution / size. But yeah, the widget documentation needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the announcement of Ice Cream Sandwich also come updated documentation on the app widgets, and I think it's a lot better. I found it very useful:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html